# Create Address Locator with HERE/Navstreets Data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, network-analyst

I just create Address Locator : Dual Range by using Streets feature class from HERE data.

[image]

But, in this HERE data, Streets Feature Class not have field for City and State. If you notice, Left City or Place. Right City or Place, Left State and Right State is blank.

In my finding, to get the full complete address in searching, we have to have City and State field.

Here data also have feature class Adminbndy1, Adminbndy2, Adminbndy3, Adminbndy4 and Adminbndy5.

But how to make use these feature classes to have relationship with Street.

How can I get information on City and State to get Full Address in searching box and complete my Address Locator?